# Nurse scheduling example: maximum hours constraint

Tags: python, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am implementing a nurse scheduling problem in Python which is similar to the example provided on [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling#nurse_scheduling).

However, I want to implement a hard constraint that each nurse is only allowed to work a maximum of 40 hours per week (each shift has different durations). How would one go about implmenting this in the context of the example (in python)?

My approach would be to create a separate list in which I define the length of each shift (typewise similar to `shift_requests` in the example). Then, run some `hours_worked` counter for each nurse and check if a given shift assignment would lead the counter to go over 40 hours. But I don't know how to implement the "check"-ing part and I am not even sure whether this is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: Something like `model.Add(sum(shift_duration[s]*shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts for d in all_days) <= 40)`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the logic of that approach? Also, if I understand this correctly it would not account for shifts being different on different days (i.e. it assumes that the two shifts (in `shift_duration`) on each day are equally long)

Comment: Constraint the sum of boolvars with the lenght of the assigment as the coefficient (constant)

Comment: To account for different durations in each shift even across days like so `model.Add(sum(shift_durations[d][s] * shifts[(n, d, s)] for d in all_days for s in all_shifts) <=  40)`, it totally works as intended. For sake of completness, this also has to be iterated over the nurses with a preceding `for n in all_nurses:`.
If you wanna write this up as an answer, I'd accept it as the correct answer.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @michif Please write the answer yourself because it may help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cudos to @Stradivari for providing this solution.

One approach is to constrain the sum of boolvars with the length of the assignment as the coefficient (constant) separately for each nurse:

```
for n in all_nurses:
   model.Add(sum(shift_durations[d][s] * \
   shifts[(n, d, s)] for d in all_days for s in all_shifts) <=  40)
```